# Selecting polygons that contain points from multiple layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have three layers (one polygon, two point), and from the polygon layer I'm trying to select any polygons that contain points from both of the points layer. It seems like a simple `Select by Location` process, but that only allows for one comparison layer, so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Select by Expression. Simply replace the names of your pointlayers:

```
overlay_contains('point1') and overlay_contains('point2')
```

Comment: Ah, I knew there had to be a simple solution. Thanks much

Answer (score 3):

You can use select by location with add to current selction.

[image]